# Alter Table Of Other User in Firebird

Tags: firebird, ddl, alter-table

When I try to alter a table from a different owner in Firebird I got this error:

```
unsuccessful metadata update
MODIFY RDB$RELATION_FIELDS failed
no permission for control access to TABLE TAGS
```

I had already granted ALL privileges to this user, also REFERENCES privileges, but I still getting this error.

Does anybody knows how to solve this?

I use Firebird 1.5

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Firebird 2.5 Language Reference section on [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-alter) states:

> Only the table owner and [administrators](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-administrators) have the authority to use
> ALTER TABLE.

In other words if you are not the owner of the table, you need to either login as `SYSDBA`, or you need to be logged in as root or Adminstrator on the machine with the database. There is - as far as I am aware - no other way to alter a table as a different user.

In Firebird 2.5 there is also the `RDB$ADMIN` role which allows a user which is granted this role to act with the same rights as SYSDBA.

The rights you can `GRANT` (except for `REFERENCES`) are only for DML, not for DDL operations.

Firebird 3 introduced [metadata privileges](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-access-sql.html#rnfb30-security-metadataprivs), which allows you to grant these permissions to a specific user or role for specific object types.

For example:

```
GRANT ALTER ANY TABLE TO Joe;
```

Will allow the user Joe to alter any tables in the current database.

Comment: AFAIK the user rights for DDL is planned for Firebird 3. This it not helping the OP right now of course...

Comment: "any users with operating system superuser privileges" this is true only for Linux versions of Firebird.

Comment: Yes, specify the role RDB$ADMIN to any other user worked for me.

Comment: I get the message "unsuccessful metadata update MODIFY TRIGGER failed no permission for control access to TABLE Table1" when I try to change the value of a field in a table (Table2) that has cascade updates applied to the changed field. Table1 is affected by the cascade update. When I sign in as SYSDBA I do not get the error message. I'm using Firebird 2.1

Comment: @JonathanElkins I suggest you ask a new question with all relevant information. But first try if granting update rights on table2 works.